# Parsing XML using XPath in Java using Google Geocode

Tags: java, xml, google-maps, xpath

```
kohaNimi = "Tallinn";
URL myUrl = new URL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + kohaNimi + "&sensor=false");
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(myUrl.openStream());
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/GeocodeResponse/result/bounds/southwest/lat");
String swLat = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING).toString();
System.out.println("swLat: " + swLat );
```

So I am trying to use Google geocode API to get the coordinates of a town, but I have trouble parsing the xml. I am trying to use xPath with Java. I can verify that ... does exist. The problem is that when I try to parse this xml I wont get any text as response. I have looked over the code and can't seem to figure out what is wrong. I used this blogpost to assemble my code: http://tunatore.wordpress.com/2011/05/20/how-to-use-xpath-i-java-simple-example/

You can verify that xpath is correct(should get response) from here: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Tallinn&sensor=false

Can anyone spot what is wrong?

Comment: What is your actual output?

Comment: I've checked the url specified (Talinn&...). The returned XML structure has no `bounds` element inside `GeocodeRespoonse/result` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
xpath.compile("/GeocodeResponse/result/bounds/southwest/lat")
```

To:

```
xpath.compile("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/bounds/southwest/lat")
```